# jQuery UI MonthPicker - set SelectedMonth after initialising

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a month using jQuery UI MonthPicker after i have initialised the MonthPicker.
My initialising code looks like this:

```
  selectedMonth=firstDay.getMonth()+1+"/"+firstDay.getFullYear();
  $('.month-picker').MonthPicker({ 
    SelectedMonth: selectedMonth,
    Button: false,
    OnAfterChooseMonth: function(selectedDate) {
        highlightMonth(selectedDate);
    } 
  });
```

I have 2 buttons (forward and backward) that are not part of the popup MonthPicker but that should update the `SelectedMonth` in the MonthPicker. I am trying like this:

```
$('.month-picker').MonthPicker({SelectedMonth:"11/2016"}); //will be replaced by dynamic data later
```

apparently this initialises a second MonthPicker, so I have 2 of them now in my .month-picker div. I cannot find how to get rid of one of them...
ideas?

Comment: Have you seen this demo page: http://jsfiddle.net/kidsysco/JeZap/ ?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter yes. but I cannot find a case like this in there

Comment: I don't understand your use case. You have buttons that are updating the monthpicker, but the buttons are not part of the monthpicker?  Do you need a monthpicker then?

Comment: yes. I need it to jump more than one month back and forth

Comment: and other reason is interface consistency (using similar mechanism when selecting weeks)